# How to fix a consistently freezing app download?

Tags: google-play-store, downloading

On my new Motorola X, I am downloading an app (Amazon's Kindle app) from the Google Play store and it is consistently getting to 91% downloading and then freezing there.

I can cancel the download and try it again, but it always stops at 91%.

Is there a way to reset the download so it truly starts from scratch? Or is there something else I should try?

Comment: I would download the apk from somewhere else and install manually, then try and install from the Play Store when an update is released.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this happens to me all the time I just go to app settings and then go to google play and them force stop and there it works

Answer (score 1):

You don't state whether it freezes up while downloading of other apps. I'm assuming it does.
What I had to do when the PlayStore froze(halted) on every download was as follows:

1) force close PlayStore, Play Services, and Services Framework

2) clear data PlayStore and Play Services

3) reboot into recovery

4) wipe dalvik-cache and cache

5) reboot

6) check the PlayStore again for working download

I've had that happen a couple of times when flashing the wrong GApps package or by not doing a simple wipe before and after flashing.

If the problem persists you will need to access your Google Account through the browser, not on your Android, but on your PC and clear your data. I don't remember the exact steps that way, but I did find info in the help files there.

The only other solution from there is to do a factory reset, just make sure you do a backup of your device before resetting. Only do the factory reset as a last resort.

Edit: one more thing you can do is run a logcat, basically a running list of what is happening at specific times during application operation. I'm not qualified to give you the right means of accomplishing that, just too much info, but I have found a wonderful write up from the XDA forums on this.
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1726238
This should show at what point the app is freezing and what is going wrong.

Good luck

Comment: Apart from these make sure you are having a stable internet connection because an un-stable internet connection (keeps turning off and on) is most likely the cause of incomplete download.

Comment: @user285oo6 the question stated that it would get to 91% each time, which would mean that the internet connection is fine. Otherwise he would end up with different completion percentages. Although more often than not, internet connection is the culprit for incomplete or failed downloads. This isn't the case with his problem, sooner or later he would eventually end up being able to complete a download.

Comment: k coz I faced a similar issue the app downloaded only 91% to 95% and my issue got resolved just by getting a constant internet connection.

Comment: @user285oo6 " I can cancel the download and try it again, but it always stops at 91%."-direct quote. So the internet connection wouldn't be an issue then.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an adblocker like adaway, it could be the cause. stopping/removing mine solved the problem.

If you still want adblocking, some browsers come with an internal ad blockers, and that doesn't seem to interfere with the store.